# Matplotlib x ticks label not regularly spaced

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I am plotting some data using seaborn as below:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='gap_ratio', data=df_gap, ax=ax1)
```

I am wondering why the x-ticks labels are not regularly spaced. As a result, I am ending with overlapping x-tick labels. Is there any way to get this fixed easily ?

FYI, the x data is regularly spaced (1 data point every minute)

[image]

Comment: Is the x data regularly spaced?

Comment: yes the x data is regularly spaced (1 minute granularity). this is why I am puzzled.

Comment: Could be that it is hiding some ticks because the label is so extensive, if you dont show the x labels does the problem continue? Also try specifying 4 or 5 x ticks to see if that problem continues

Comment: Could you add some reproducible test data? How many rows are there? E.g. try `x = pd.date_range('20220101', freq='1min', periods=N)` and `y = np.random.rand(N)`.  Your plot gives the impression that there is a second subplot placed at the same position. Could you try to make a full stand-alone example?

Comment: Once you find a subset that can reproduce the issue, a good way to share it for others is by pasting the `to_dict()` output. For example if `df_gap.head(15)` can repro the issue, edit the question to include the output of `print(df_gap.head(15).to_dict())`